# regex expression to accept ENTER key in string

Tags: c#, regex

### Issue

---

I am having an issue creating a regex to accept any string and the ENTER key, at the moment i have this:

```
^$|^.+$
```

I have looked around and people have said to add `\n` but this does not work.

An example of the string is should allow is as follows:

```
Hello this is a test string


and i want this to be accepted
```

Comment: It seems you need `(?s)^.*$`. However, what good is this regex that matches all, incl. empty, strings? Could you please precise the requirements?

Comment: `\n` is **not** "the enter key", it's a **Line Feed**

Comment: Why do you need regex? More specifically, what are you trying to do that requires you to receive an enter key in a string using regex? Is it a console based app? You tagged the question c#, but there's no c# code or anything that relates to c# here. More to the point: are you looking for new lines in a string (that is, the enter key's representation in a series of characters), or to accept a string as input?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Basically its a C# windows service application where we want to handle validation through an engine in SQL. We are then able to change the Validation as we wish without doing a an update to the product. In a few weeks we will be tightening the validation on some things but for now we have it in place.

Comment: So, is it just a matter of adding `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag to your regex? Like `new Regex(@"^.*$", RegexOptions.Singleline)`?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `s` flag on the regex engine. This will ensure that the `.` metacharacter will match newlines.

Here's a [link to a working example](https://regex101.com/r/tA0aT4/1).

Also, as a sidenote, instead of `^$|^.+$` you can condense the whole expression to `^.*$` to achieve the same results with better performance.

---

Comment: s is whitespace, not multiline

Comment: `\s` is whitespace. The `m` flag is multiline, but that's not what I'm referencing. The `s` flag is single-line mode, making `.` match newline characters. View the example if you're confused about the distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you need the [RegexOptions.Singleline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) option.  See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292163/regular-expression-match-variable-multiple-lines) for more information.

Here is a quick example that really just matches the entire string, so it's not useful.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^.*$",
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

In your future validation code, you need to replace `.*` with whatever your validation will be.